# Php redirect on custom Post/get from webform

Tags: php, forms, redirect

Hi all this is an easy question but right now i can't think about ..

I've a form where people can insert a personal code like "Abcdef301"

On submit i want to redirect them to url:

http://domain.tld/yoururls/Abcdef301

I've tried with some Post and Get (like the emails form but i've failed)

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['VAI'])) {
    if(isset($_POST['text']) && $_POST['text'] != "") {
        header("Location: http://domain.tld/yoururls/".$_POST['text']);
    } else {
        // handle error of no code in form field here if you want to
    }
}
?>

<html>

<head>
    <title>page title</title>
</head>

<div id="feedback-form"> 
    <div class="success-block"></div>
        <form action="" method="post">
            <input name="text" placeholder="Inserire Codice Evento" required type="text">
            <input type="submit" value="VAI" class="btn">
        </form>
    </div>
</html>
```

Should be what you're looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm too noob to edit all

this is my form

 <div id="feedback-form">
                    <div class="success-block"></div>
                    <form action="http:/domain.it/code/send.php" method="post">
                        <input name="text" placeholder="Inserire Codice Evento" required type="text">
                        <input type="submit" value="VAI" class="btn">
                    </form>
                </div>

Can you write the correct php?

Thanks

Comment: I updated it to your field and submit button names. You just need to add the code I posted above the html code in your file. You can at least try hard enough to do that yourself. I also added a bit to show you how to check if the code exists in the form field. Again, this should get you started, but you need to at least try a little.

Comment: Thanks for the help but isn't working stuck on the send.php page :/

Comment: It can all be one page... no need for the send.php

Comment: Thanks solved :)

<?php
if(isset($_POST['VAI']));
 {
    header("Location: http://domain.tld/yoururls/".$_POST['text']);
}
?>

Comment: Also, you would have no need for the success block. As soon as the user submits a valid code, you are going to redirect them to a new URL. They would never see the success message. Success instead is indicated by them making it to the page they desired.